# Mappable parameter for date without time

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am implementing an API that has the following requirement:

> The due date should be sent in the format without time.

How can this be done? The Integromat docs mention a boolean ["time" parameter](http://%20https://docs.integromat.com/apps/other/parameters/date#date-and-time-input) of the date object, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

The question is: how do I make this: `"spent_on": "2020-02-19T23:00:00.000Z"` look like this: `"spent_on": "2020-02-20"`?

```
 {
   "name": "spent_on",
   "label": "Spent on the Date",
   "type": "date",
   "time": false,
   "required": true
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you figured it out by now, but if now: You have formatDate within Integromat in the text field. Then you would see formatDate(2020-02-19T23:00:00.000Z; YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: how can you do this in the interface?